# Parquet runs out of memory on reading

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, bigdata, parquet

I am trying to multiply against a large matrix that is stored in parquet format, so am being careful not to store the RDD in memory, but am getting an OOM error from the parquet reader:

```
15/12/06 05:23:36 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 950.0 in stage 4.0   
(TID 28398, 172.31.34.233): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:755)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:494)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:127)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:208)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:201)
...
```

Specifically, the matrix is a 46752-by-54843120 dense matrix of 32-bit floats that is stored in parquet format (each row is about 1.7GB uncompressed).

The following code loads this matrix as a Spark IndexedRowMatrix and multiplies it by a random vector (the rows are stored with an associated string label, and the floats have to be converted to doubles because IndexedRows can only use doubles):

```
val rows = {
  sqlContext.read.parquet(datafname).rdd.map {
    case SQLRow(rowname: String, values: WrappedArray[Float]) =>
    // DenseVectors have to be doubles
      val vector = new DenseVector(values.toArray.map(v => v.toDouble)) 
      new IndexedRow(indexLUT(rowname), vector)
    }
}

val nrows : Long = 46752
val ncols = 54843120
val A = new IndexedRowMatrix(rows, nrows, ncols)
A.rows.unpersist() // doesn't help avoid OOM

val x = new DenseMatrix(ncols, 1, BDV.rand(ncols).data)
A.multiply(x).rows.collect
```

I am using the following options when running

```
--driver-memory 220G
--num-executors 203
--executor-cores 4
--executor-memory 25G
--conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0
```

There are 25573 partitions to the parquet file, so the uncompressed Float values of each partition should be less than 4Gb; I expect this should imply that the current executor memory is much more than sufficient (I cannot raise the executor-memory setting).

Any ideas why this is running into OOM errors and how to fix it? As far as I can tell, there's no reason for the parquet reader to be storing anything.

Comment: I think that the OOME is given on the creation the the dense vector. Can you check for that?

Comment: Wouldn't that show up by Breeze throwing the error instead of Parquet? Also, I can use the same set up and do an e.g. take(10) from the rdd to get a few rows, it's just the multiply operation that craps out, so I think something in Parquet is accumulating memory without freeing it on the executors.

Comment: Are you loading 25573 parquet files? Please post the code that loads your input data. There's a bug in spark about creating RDDs from different paths.

Comment: the question contains the code that loads the input data, where I assign the RDD to rows. I believe there were 25573 files within the parquet dataset named in datafname (I don't know the appropriate terminology, but it's one parquet dataset which Spark stored as 25573 files within the directory named by datafname)

Comment: @AatG I know this question is old, but did you solve it? I was wondering if the reason for you OOM wasn't because everything was processed on the driver? Since Spark does lazy evaluation and your only action is a `collect` (gathering all data to the driver), I suspect your job is not distributed at all?

Comment: Sorry, now seeing your comment Glennie. I believe it (and a couple other Parquet issues I had) went away in the next version of Spark.